# How can I add progress bar to vue-strap carousel slider?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have imported the [vue-strap carousel component](http://yuche.github.io/vue-strap/#carousel) in my project and it's working well, but I need to also add progress bar to it. Is there a way to integrate or add a progress bar to the vue-strap carousel ?

Example of progress bar component:

https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-progressbar

Answer (score -1):

I'm not Vue expert, but I think, that there is no direct solution to your problem, because Carousel does not emit any events with info about what is currently shown. I can think of 2 workarounds:

1. Hack VueStrap:

   - add emit of slide event to Carousel object
   - add some enumeration to items, for example add them props with id, so that you can send this ID with slide event
2. Create wrapper around Carousel. Listen for click event, then in handler for click event, select with jQuery all items, and loop through them, looking for the one with `active` class.

Knowing which item is active, and knowing their ammount, you can use `set(progress)` method of progressbar, to set it properly.